# Travelling to EU Schengen area

Tags: visas, uk, schengen

I am a non-EU citizen but have UK residency. What is the best way for me to obtain a visa to visit the Schengen area.

Comment: What is your nationality? Often it makes a difference when it comes to gettng visa.

Comment: What do you mean? Apply? And answer truthfully.

Comment: There's up to 26 different answers because the policy is decided on a member-by-member basis. But if you have a UK visa issued for GREATER  than 6 months, you can generally apply locally in the UK.

Comment: The best way to obtain a visa is to apply for one, and follow all the instructions on the forms carefully. That seems obvious, so what's your actual question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Come up with a plan for the trip, make sure you have the money to afford it, and make the application at the right embassy or consulate (depending on which Schengen countries you want to see).

- As an UK resident, you will face *relatively* little suspicion that you are an illegal immigrant, because legal residency in the UK is usually better than an illegal stay or an asylum application in a Schengen country.
- Living in the UK, you probably have sufficient income to afford the trip, too.